# What is the USB plug on the Mini-Display Port to Dual-DVI adapter used for?

Tags: usb, mac-pro, dvi

http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB571Z/A/mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-adapter

What is the USB plug used for?

Answer (score 2):

The Dual Link DVI connector is an active adapter, and requires a power source (which Mini-DP cannot supply). It uses the USB as a source of power to power the adapter.